# Polyline changes the order of points

Tags: leaflet

I would like leaflet to connect points in polyline in the same order as they were passed into constructor (L.polyline(route, routeOptions).addTo(map) where route is an array of points), but it seems to me that polyline does not care about order at all. Any suggestions would be highly appreciated.

Comment: Sorry, it was my fault, i created an array of points by iterating through object. It was the reason of the "weird" ordering

Answer (score 1):

What makes you think that Leaflet polyline does not care at all about the order in the array of points (coordinates)?

`L.polyline(arrayOfLatLngs)` should draw a segmented line passing by all the specified coordinates in `arrayOfLatLngs`, in the order they are set in the array.

Demo: http://jsfiddle.net/ve2huzxw/91/

If it does not behave that way for you, please provide your code and if possible reproduce your issue online (e.g. on jsfiddle) so that people can investigate.